# Sony Xperia M4 Start Screen almost black

Tags: screen, sony-xperia

After a reboot, my new xperia always starts with this screen:

[image: Black screen]

I have the same problem in 'Safe Mode'.

What can I do? I want to fix this problem without a factory reset.

Edit:
I found more people with same problem on Sony's forum. I fixed reseting to factory using PC Companion: https://talk.sonymobile.com/t5/Xperia-M4-Aqua/M4-Aqua-won-t-start/m-p/1025996/thread-id/1311

Comment: When was the first time you encountered this issue? Do you remember what you were doing when the issue first appeared? Is the Android rooted? What is your Android version?

Comment: I'm using Sony's android 5.0. It's the first time i got this problem. Android isn't rooted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found more people with same problem on Sony's forum.

I fixed reseting to factory using PC Companion: https://talk.sonymobile.com/t5/Xperia-M4-Aqua/M4-Aqua-won-t-start/m-p/1025996/thread-id/1311